# An unknown error has occured in the Java remote_api handler for this call

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm trying to use bulkloader to load entities to my GAE app, which is already hosted on GAE. **I'm not using DEV server now.** It was all fine couple of weeks ago, when I left the app, now after like 2 or 3 updates of GoogleAppEngineLauncher to 1.9 I can't use same commands as before to load entities, because it ends with tons of errors:

```
[INFO    ] Connecting to my-app.appspot.com/remote_api
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/appcfg.py", line 126, in <module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "/usr/local/bin/appcfg.py", line 122, in run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
  File "/Applications/ADT/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 4934, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "/Applications/ADT/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 4925, in main
    result = AppCfgApp(argv).Run()
  File "/Applications/ADT/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 2648, in Run
    self.action(self)
  File "/Applications/ADT/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 4605, in __call__
    return method()
  File "/Applications/ADT/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 4417, in PerformUpload
    run_fn(args)
  File "/Applications/ADT/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 4298, in RunBulkloader
    sys.exit(bulkloader.Run(arg_dict))
  File "/Applications/ADT/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/bulkloader.py", line 4408, in Run
    return _PerformBulkload(arg_dict)
  File "/Applications/ADT/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/bulkloader.py", line 4273, in _PerformBulkload
    loader.finalize()
  File "/Applications/ADT/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/bulkload/bulkloader_config.py", line 382, in finalize
    self.reserve_keys(self.keys_to_reserve)
  File "/Applications/ADT/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/bulkloader.py", line 1217, in ReserveKeys
    datastore._GetConnection()._reserve_keys(ConvertKeys(keys))
  File "/Applications/ADT/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py", line 2108, in _reserve_keys
    self._async_reserve_keys(None, keys).get_result()
  File "/Applications/ADT/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py", line 890, in get_result
    results = self.__rpcs[0].get_result()
  File "/Applications/ADT/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 612, in get_result
    return self.__get_result_hook(self)
  File "/Applications/ADT/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py", line 2151, in __reserve_keys_hook
    self.check_rpc_success(rpc)
  File "/Applications/ADT/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py", line 1331, in check_rpc_success
    rpc.check_success()
  File "/Applications/ADT/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 578, in check_success
    self.__rpc.CheckSuccess()
  File "/Applications/ADT/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_rpc.py", line 156, in _WaitImpl
    self.request, self.response)
  File "/Applications/ADT/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py", line 200, in MakeSyncCall
    self._MakeRealSyncCall(service, call, request, response)
  File "/Applications/ADT/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py", line 236, in _MakeRealSyncCall
    raise UnknownJavaServerError("An unknown error has occured in the "
google.appengine.ext.remote_api.remote_api_stub.UnknownJavaServerError: An unknown error has occured in the Java remote_api handler for this call.
```

AppEngine is written in JAVA, however I use python sdk to use bulkloader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same day I used Datastore Admin to wipe app database. This uses much quotas, and this is why upload was failing (just guessing). Still it's weird since my project has billing enabled.